# Read .ocx assembly version from Javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

I am running a client solution based on ActiveX controls, built around a main .ocx file.

This file is versioned and I was wondering whether there was any way for us to check the version of the ocx file itself (see screenshot) from Javascript.

[image]

Comment: As in from IE hosting the ocx?

Comment: Yes, the browser will be IE. The whole check must be performed via javascript to present a pop-up with the link to a more recent version if the one in the file is out of date